# flutter/dart connect to Azure via mqtts

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect to our MQTT server on Azure.

I use MQTTBox as our testbed, and it is successfully connecting to
protocol: mqtts
host: .azure-devices.net/$iothub/websocket
user: .azure-devices.net/testdevice/?api-version=2018-06-30
password: 'SharedAccessSignature sr=.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Ftestdevice&sig=xxxxxxx'

I tried the mqtt_client library, which was an issue with "$" sign in the server endpoint and throws ""SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'mqttQueue.azure-devices.net/$iothub/websocket' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)"

```
final client = MqttServerClient('<hubname>.azure-devices.net/\$iothub/websocket', '');
client.port = 8883;
client.secure = true;

final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .authenticateAs('<hubname>.azure-devices.net/testdevice/?api-version=2018-06-30',
      'SharedAccessSignature sr=<hubname>.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Ftestdevice&sig=xxxxxxx')
      .withClientIdentifier('testdevice')
      .withWillTopic('devices/testdevice/messages/events/') // If you set this you must set a will message
      .withWillMessage('My Will message')
      .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
      .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);

client.connectionMessage = connMess;

try {
  await client.connect();
}
```

I also tried unsuccessfully

```
final client = MqttServerClient('HostName=<hubname>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=testDevice;SharedAccessKey=m....Y=','')
```

Any working example to Azure in dart/flutter is appreciated, as I fail to map the Azure given parameters to the parameters in the library.

Comment: I suspect you need to pass in a URL (e.g. `MqttServerClient('wss://<hubname>.azure-devices.net/\$iothub/websocke', '')`) as per the [example](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/blob/master/example/mqtt_server_client_websocket.dart#L28).

Comment: That only applies to web sockets :-(. Per the developer, for mqtts, the hostname should ONLY be the hostname ready for nslookup, not a fully formed URL with the protocol prefix or any path.

Comment: I had assumed you were using websockets (the link does end with `/websocket`...). If you are not using websockets then including the path makes no sense (so yes you will need to provide a raw hostname/IP and port).

Comment: Finally found the answer:
a) MqttServerClient('mqttQueue.azure-devices.net', '') without any paths/protocols as you need in MQTTbox and other test platforms
b) .authenticateAs('<hubname>.azure-devices.net/testdevice, ,...) without the protocol, which is documented incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
final client = MqttServerClient('<hubname>.azure-devices.net', '');
client.useWebSocket = false;
client.port = 8883;
client.autoReconnect = true;
client.keepAlivePeriod = 3600;

final String user = '<hubname>.azure-devices.net/<your device id>';
late String password; // <== password string is obtained elsewhere
final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .withClientIdentifier(clientIdentifier)
      .startClean();
client.connectionMessage = connMess; 
client.connect(username, password);
```